# Safe Way to "Stay Loggedin" with Sessions [Still Need Answers]

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-variables, session-cookies

I use the $_SESSION variable to log users in. Are they safe from Injections?

If you wish to have a look at my scripts to check for vulnerability's Here you go: http://pastebin.com/raw/7iiSSjKP

So thanks to a user below they linked me to: http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/session-hijacking-cheat-sheet/

It looks like my sessions are being stored exactly the same as the InfoSec website's vulnerabilities. And yes, It is vulnerable. [image: 1]

I tested and the PHPSESSID cookie stored on the browser is exploitable, If I inject a different users cookie I will be logged into there account and vice-versa. If I stay on there cookie, logout and login to my own account, they will be logged into my account.
(Bottom msg and top 2 msgs are me other ones are my friend bean)[image: 2]

How can I fix this?
I have read around a lot and apparently a SSL certificate just solves this, I do have a SSL certificate but it doesn't seem to change anything. What do I do to solve this?!

Methods I have tried:

1. http://pastebin.com/raw/5skKhPSw (Seems to work at first and it would make sense to work but if you log into other accounts and vice-versa it just messes up here and there so its not a great solution.
2. Dont know any other way. Open to Suggestions.

Comment: You shouldn't have any issues using Cookies. The vulnerabilities in cookie injection are reliant on the user being dimwitted enough to allow someone to have their cookie

Comment: @iJamesPHP I know that but like surely theres some way to protect that right?

Comment: There's no way to protect your site against the stupidity of users and their details. You could make a database and log the cookie id with the user's ip and if the ip logging in eith a cookie is different, ask them to log in

Comment: @iJamesPHP Yes but thats almost never efficient. Are you saying no website has protection against this?

Comment: Still need an answer about this. Appreciate it if anyone could help in some way.

Comment: As has already been said there is no need for any hardcoded security around this. Any fix would be inneficient and pointless.

Comment: @iJamesPHP Well how does YouTube e.t.c get around this then?

Comment: They don't. Anybody who knows what they're doing can cookie jack Google / YT

Comment: @iJamesPHP I see. I appreciate it I guess. Could you add that as an answer?

Comment: It's not exactly an answer but just a point. Just mark the answer below and be done with it. I hope you get it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

`$_SESSION` are usually used for logins, thus they are reasonably safe by default, as a user won't be able to somehow set the `$_SESSION['username']` value themselves; the value can only be set by your server.

However, there are still vulnerabilities about `$_SESSION`, more specifically session hijacking, this is the only real vulnerability to the whole scheme.

---

Also, after `header("Location: http://gameshare.io");`, you should use `exit;`.

**Setting a header will not terminate the current script.** Thus, if you're outputting sensitive information after this line, it will be sent to the client! You need to explicitly exit after setting the header.

Comment: Thanks for the information, Could you explain Session Hijacking to me?

Comment: @ShinyMK A brief introduction at http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/session-hijacking-cheat-sheet/

Comment: [Hmmm...](https://i.gyazo.com/88ec227aea9539383104c6d18efee36f.png) This looks interesting. From what I can understand from the cookies you can just straight up copy and paste the cookies with a Cookie Injector right? Then the user refreshes and boom logged in?

Comment: Yup I was kinda right. Can anyone here who is good at this check my website: https://gameshare.io/login and see if its vulnerable? I dont believe XSS is vulnerable as my host blocks it.

Comment: Oh also I applied "exit;" after the Header() appreciate it.